# Pointer of generic type

Tags: c#, pointers, generics

Why is the use of pointers to generic types invalid in C#? `int?*` is invalid, whereas `typeof(int?).MakePointerType()` doesn't produce an exception.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx), a pointer can be of:

> sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, or bool.
>
> Any enum type.
>
> Any pointer type.
>
> Any user-defined struct type that contains fields of unmanaged types only.

I don't see any limitation relating to generics. `int?` looks valid, as it contains only a `bool` and `int` field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote the C# 5.0 specification §18.2 Pointer Types

> Unlike references (values of reference types), pointers are not
> tracked by the garbage collector—the garbage collector has no
> knowledge of pointers and the data to which they point. For this
> reason a pointer is not permitted to point to a reference or to a
> struct that contains references, and the referent type of a pointer
> must be an unmanaged-type.
>
> An unmanaged-type is any type that isn’t a
> reference-type or constructed type, and doesn’t contain reference-type
> or constructed type fields at any level of nesting. In other words, an
> unmanaged-type is one of the following:
>
> - sbyte, byte, short, ushort,
>   int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, or bool.
> - Any
>   enum-type.
> - Any pointer-type.
> - Any user-defined struct-type that is
>   not a constructed type and contains fields of unmanaged-types only.

The key section that is stopping you is a the `constructed type` restriction.

from §1.6.3 Type parameters (emphasis mine)

> A generic type with type arguments provided, like `Pair<int,string>` above, **is called a constructed type**.

Any generic type where you specify the type parameters is considered a constructed type and constructed types are not allowed to be in pointers. That is why `Nullable<int>` is not allowed.

Comment: Okay, MSDN probably forgot to list this, but what interests me is why it was decided to disallow generic types.

Comment: For that you can only hope that [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) sees your question and responds, but beyond that it is unlikely you will get an answer to "Why" it was done. EDIT: however one clue could be [that feature did not get enough points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)